# Pass a column as an argument inside UDF Body

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have the following dataframe :

```
+---------+----------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+
|CAR_OWNER|MOTOR_TYPE|ELECTRIFICATION_RATIO|ENERGY_IN_US|ENERGY_OUTSIDE_US|
+---------+----------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+
|     Alex|Electrical|                  1.0|          15|                0|
|      Bob| Thermical|                  0.0|           0|                5|
|   Claire|    Hybrid|                  0.5|           0|               10|
+---------+----------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+
```

Using the following function :

```
def associateEnergy(motorType: String, consumedEnergy: Float, consumptionType: String, elecRatio: Float): Float =
motorType match {
  case "Electrical" => if (consumptionType == "ELEC") consumedEnergy else 0f
  case "Thermical"  => if (consumptionType == "THERM") consumedEnergy else 0f
  case "Hybrid"     => if (consumptionType == "ELEC") consumedEnergy * elecRatio else consumedEnergy * (1 - elecRatio)
}
```

I wanna compute the following fields :

- ELEC_ENERGY_IN_US
- ELEC_ENERGY_OUTSIDE_US
- THERM_ENERGY_IN_US
- THERM_ENERGY_IN_US

Which I can do using the following Udf :

```
def associateEnergyUdf(consumptionType: String) = udf(
    (motorType: String, consumedEnergy: Float, elecRatio: Float) =>
      associateEnergy(motorType, consumedEnergy, consumptionType, elecRatio)
  )
```

and this piece of code :

```
inputDf
    .withColumn("ELEC_ENERGY_IN_US", associateEnergyUdf("ELEC")(col("MOTOR_TYPE"), col("ENERGY_IN_US"), col("ELECTRIFICATION_RATIO")))
    .withColumn("ELEC_ENERGY_OUTSIDE_US", associateEnergyUdf("ELEC")(col("MOTOR_TYPE"), col("ENERGY_OUTSIDE_US"), col("ELECTRIFICATION_RATIO")))
    .withColumn("THERM_ENERGY_IN_US", associateEnergyUdf("THERM")(col("MOTOR_TYPE"), col("ENERGY_IN_US"), col("ELECTRIFICATION_RATIO")))
    .withColumn("THERM_ENERGY_OUTSIDE_US", associateEnergyUdf("THERM")(col("MOTOR_TYPE"), col("ENERGY_OUTSIDE_US"), col("ELECTRIFICATION_RATIO")))
```

But I don't want to repeat four times the *col("MOTOR_TYPE")* and *col("ELECTRIFICATION_RATIO")* arguments. So I created the following udf :

```
def associateEnergyReducedUdf(consumptionType: String)(consumedEnergyCol: Column) = udf(
    () => associateEnergyUdf(consumptionType)(col("MOTOR_TYPE"), consumedEnergyCol, col("ELECTRIFICATION_RATIO"))
  )
```

so that I only need to call :

```
inputDf
    .withColumn("ELEC_ENERGY_IN_US", associateEnergyReducedUdf("ELEC")(col("ENERGY_IN_US"))())
    .withColumn("ELEC_ENERGY_OUTSIDE_US", associateEnergyReducedUdf("ELEC")(col("ENERGY_OUTSIDE_US"))())
    .withColumn("THERM_ENERGY_IN_US", associateEnergyReducedUdf("THERM")(col("ENERGY_IN_US"))())
    .withColumn("THERM_ENERGY_OUTSIDE_US", associateEnergyReducedUdf("THERM")(col("ENERGY_OUTSIDE_US"))())
```

But this results in the following error :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Column is not supported
```

How can I achieve that without repeating unnecessary arguments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reduced UDF, you wrap an already existing UDF into another UDF. Try instead:

```
def associateEnergyReducedUdf(consumptionType: String)(consumedEnergyCol: Column) =
      () => associateEnergyUdf(consumptionType)(col("MOTOR_TYPE"), consumedEnergyCol, col("ELECTRIFICATION_RATIO"))
```

This works